# Mifare Classic Emulation Not Working & I haven't found a complete code or step-by-step guide for Mifare Classic emulation

Tags: nfc, emulation, mifare, hce

I attempted to implement Mifare Classic Emulation using an HCE (Host Card Emulation) Service, but I encountered issues with its functionality.

Here's what I did: I created an HCE service and attempted to emulate static data. However, when I placed my phone near an NFC reader (specifically the [*ACR1255U-J1*](https://www.amazon.in/1255U-Mobile-Smart-Reader-White/dp/B01MFFT8B2) that I purchased from Amazon), I didn't receive any response or activity from the reader. Consequently, my attempt to emulate data was unsuccessful.

I'm seeking guidance on how to properly implement Mifare Classic emulation. I'm wondering if there's any involvement of a Secure Element role or other steps that need to be taken.

My goal is to create an Android application that can emulate Mifare Classic cards. The purpose of this application is to enable NFC-supported locks to be unlocked or locked using my app.

Answer (score 1):

HCE in Android only emulates NFC Type 4A Tags, it cannot emulate the non NFC standard Mifare Classic Cards.

Comment: Is there any particular reason that, HCE in Android support only type 4A tags emulation. Why we can't emulate using Mifare Classic Tag?
Is there any other solutions by which we can emulate Mifare Classic Tag?

Comment: Mifare Classic is propitiatory format for NXP, other manufacturers of NFC hardware are not going to support that for various reasons and thus it is not part of the NFC standards. Type 4A is supported as it is the most flexible and widely used of the NFC standards. I think there are some USB readers from NXP that support Mifare Classic emulation in the reader hardware, with a phone that supports USB OTG you might be able to get the USB reader to emulate a Mifare Classic Tag.

Comment: If you have implemented this kind of code using any tag can you please share it?