# NFC emulation in Phones

Tags: nfc, passkit, homekit

I am looking for a way to unlock door lock using NFC from phone as shown in these videos:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISxnUqb5_8Y&t=65s
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_IIDq5IS6I0
3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7jq_pOwf9bo

Initially I tried to figure out emulation of NFC card, but numerous posts state that it is not possible to emulate NFC from phones.

I tried emulation of Mifare Classic 1k protocol but it is not possible, I wanted to know which protocol these locks use so I can look forward to emulate it in apps. The reason I tried Mifare Classic is my client informed me his card is Mifare Classic. I am bit clueless here.

But the guys in the video are doing something, I wonder if it is possible with rooting phone. If yes, what emulation should be used?

Comment: please explain the question without resorting to external resources

Comment: Did you have any luck with this @Calvin? Can you share your findings?

Comment: I concluded that 1k classic is proprietary protocol it is not possible to use it in phone, so I have dropped the project. There are other ways but to me it seemed so many entities needs to get involved, like phone manufacturer, ISP, or may be the lock manufacturer, to get things into Secure Element of the phone. @Lizozom
The above is for Android, for iOS just get a HomeKit enabled lock and seemingly things work OOB, my client was not interested in iOS only solution so did not explore further..

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in phone hardware, on Android as a normal developer you can do [Host Card Emulation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce) HCE on iPhone, Apple restrict that to themselves but they do support [Passkit](https://passkit.com/) in Apple Wallet.

Comment: I tried emulation of Mifare Classic 1k protocol, but it is not possible, I wanted to know which protocol these locks use so I can look forward to emulating it in apps. It is for one of my clients and per him, his lock gets unlocked using Mifare Classic card. I have been trying to emulate it since couple of months now without luck.

Comment: As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/76850393/2373819 most hardware won't emulate this propitiatory mifare format.

Comment: Yes, I figured out that, by any chance you know how these guys make the door unlock using phones?